# rsync no such file or directory (2)

Tags: windows-7, windows, sync, rsync

I am running rysnc to 32 bits windows 7 virtual machine. I have installed cwRsync for 32 bits which installs rsync.exe that I am trying to run but it just does't work. I  have of course added path of rsync.exe to PATH

As a simple test I want to sync `c:\test\one` folder to `c:\test\two` but see the error in the image attached.

I have used rsync before on windows a while ago but I don't know why this time, it just doesn't work.

[image]

Comment: Last time I tried similar I would up with and rsync which did not do file to file copies on the same host.  Can you verify that this version can do that?

Comment: @Hennes I downloaded this time from [here](https://www.itefix.net/cwrsync) and I thought all version can sync on same host.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `/cygdrive/c/test/one` instead of `/c/test/one`. Same for the destination path.

Comment: That did the trick but what is `cygdrive`? I was also having nightmare using `xcopy *.h e:\project c:\project /s` and that just didn't update the files even though output said it does..does it has to do with cygdrive as well?

Comment: `cygdrive` if a virtual directory that contains all your windows drives. This trick is necessary since `rsync` only handles Unix paths. Don't forget to accept this answer ;)

Comment: thanks previously I append only / to path with rsync and that had worked, this is new to me. At that time I was using mingw toolkit and this time it came from cwRsync, I wonder if its because of that?